# Translating Apple Photos Sample to Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to convert `apple's` `Photos` sample to `Swift` to suite my needs. But, I always have problem when I see this sign `^` in Objective-C. So, trying to try and clear it up and understand it if anyone would like to explain to me.

This is the code I am trying to convert

```
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    // Loop through the section fetch results, replacing any fetch results that have been updated.
    NSMutableArray *updatedSectionFetchResults = [self.sectionFetchResults mutableCopy];
    __block BOOL reloadRequired = NO;

    [self.sectionFetchResults enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(PHFetchResult *collectionsFetchResult, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {
        PHFetchResultChangeDetails *changeDetails = [changeInstance changeDetailsForFetchResult:collectionsFetchResult];

        if (changeDetails != nil) {
            [updatedSectionFetchResults replaceObjectAtIndex:index withObject:[changeDetails fetchResultAfterChanges]];
            reloadRequired = YES;
        }
    }];

    if (reloadRequired) {
        self.sectionFetchResults = updatedSectionFetchResults;
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }

});
```

And here is my swift code.

```
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        let updatedSectionFetchResults = self.sectionFetchResults.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableArray
        let reloadRequired: Bool = false
        self.sectionFetchResults.enumerateObjectsUsingBlock(collectionsFetchResult: PHFetchResult, index: NSInteger, stop: Bool) {
            let chageDetails: PHFetchResultChangeDetails = changeInstance.changeDetailsForFetchResult(collectionsFetchResult)
            if changeDetails != nil {
                updatedSectionFetchResults.replaceObjectAtIndex(index, withObject: changeDetails.fetchResultAfterChanges)
            }
        }
        })
```

This line `self.sectionFetchResults.enumerateObjectsUsingBlock(collectionsFetchResult: PHFetchResult, index: NSInteger, stop: Bool)` I keep getting `Extra argument collectionFetchResult in call`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ^ symbol typically indicates where an Objective-C block name could appear.

Often times, the name is not specified resulting in an *anonymous block.*

http://goshdarnblocksyntax.com/ is a helpful quick reference for the most common forms that blocks can take in Objective-C.

The [Apple documentation on blocks](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html) is also a valuable reference for understanding the different forms.

With Swift, closures have taken the place of blocks and operate in much the same way with a different syntax. There is a corresponding quick reference for closures at http://goshdarnclosuresyntax.com/.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer helped me focus my search more on how to solve it.